# What is the best way to do knowledge transfer?

Tags: software-industry, new-job, resignation, documentation, planning

I have just joined the team around three months and the lead developer is resigning. I just have two months worth of time on learning the devops, the workflow and the internal code of the application. For now, we don't have a wiki or a document containing the functionalities of the application

My main questions are:

Do i ask him to have a one hour session weekly to share his knowledge?
Is there a recommended offboarding process for developers? It would help to know how do other software companies do their offboarding (or how to go find out they do it).
How should that process be documented?

Comment: This feels way too broad to cover here. Perhaps a more limited "*What are the key things to do during a (key) colleagues' notice period?*" would be answerable.

Answer (score 2):

1.
No joke. Invite him to a dinner, have a friendly talk. Better with beer. Start friendly conversations. Your purpose is remain friends and have his phone number.

2.
During the session with him, when you both sit side by side next to his computer, ask him what is strongest side of his work. Express gratitude and surprise , surprise of "how you manager all that alone"...Gratitude - "It is a pleasure to have an opportunity to learn all that stuff! I'm so grateful!"

3.
Go over code, collect questions, ask them.
Loop.
Do not try to force him write WIKIes, better sit and listen, try to understand, ask questions.